# MYSQL select latest result based on ID within JOIN to prevent duplicates

Tags: mysql

Here is the query I have now

```
SELECT
list.WorkOrder,
list.Address,
list.Subdivision,
list.Section,
locateparsed.LocateParsedID,
locateparsed.WorkDate
FROM list
LEFT JOIN locateparsed ON locateparsed.WorkOrder = list.WorkOrder
WHERE list.Completed = 0
AND locateparsed.WorkDate IS NOT NULL
```

Output looks something like

```
WorkOrder | Address   | Subdivision | Section | LocateParsedID | WorkDate
12345678  | 123 test  | test        | sec 1   |             75 | 01/01/0101
12345678  | 123 test  | test        | sec 1   |             10 | 01/01/0101
12345680  | 1233 test | test        | sec 1   |             55 | 01/01/0101
12345644  | 1234 test | test        | sec 1   |             96 | 01/01/0101
12345555  | 1235 test | test        | sec 1   |             35 | 01/01/0101
```

How I want my output since 75 is higher than 10

```
WorkOrder | Address  | Subdivision | Section | LocateParsedID | WorkDate
12345678 | 123 test  | test        | sec 1   |             75 | 01/01/0101
12345680 | 1233 test | test        | sec 1   |             55 | 01/01/0101
12345644 | 1234 test | test        | sec 1   |             96 | 01/01/0101
12345555 | 1235 test | test        | sec 1   |             35 | 01/01/0101
```

Comment: pull the MAX of that column

Comment: SELECT MAX(locateparsed.LocateParsedID) returns one row. I need it to return all but only the highest LocateParsedID when a duplicate WorkOrder is returned

Answer (score 0):

You can use a derived table containing maximum `Section` value per `WorkOrder`. You can join to this table to filter out duplicates:

```
SELECT l1.WorkOrder,
       l1.Address,
       l1.Subdivision,
       l1.Section,
       lp.LocateParsedID,
       lp.WorkDate
FROM list AS l1
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT WorkOrder, MAX(Section) AS Section
   FROM list
   GROUP BY WorkOrder
) AS l2 ON l1.WorkOrder = l2.WorkOrder AND l1.Section = l2.Section
INNER JOIN locateparsed AS lp
   ON lp.WorkOrder = l2.WorkOrder
WHERE l1.Completed = 0 AND lp.WorkDate IS NOT NULL
```

**Note:** The `LEFT JOIN` is essentially an `INNER JOIN` due to the `WorkDate IS NOT NULL` being placed in the `WHERE` clause instead of the `ON` clause.

Comment: @TaylorReed You've edited the sample data. Try to use the same techique on `locateparsed` table.

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'LocateParsedID' in 'field list'